# access method or data member not found error

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub ProvinceID_AfterUpdate()


Me.City.RowSource = "SELECT CityName FROM" & " City WHERE ProvinceID = " & Me.ProvinceID & "Order BY ProvinceID"

Me.City = Me.City.ItemData(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no question nor did you tell in which line you get the error. Please read [ask] and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct syntax and spacing. 
Also, it doesn't make sense to Order By the filter. So, try:

```
Me!City.RowSource = "SELECT CityName FROM City WHERE ProvinceID = " & Me.ProvinceID & " ORDER BY CityName"
```